# Is there a common term for an editable/searchable drop down field?

Tags: design-patterns, search, drop-down-list, combobox

What is the common name or design pattern for a UI element which is like a combobox but has the added facility of typing to refine the options returned in the drop down.

Comment: what are the options listed in the drop down ?

Comment: Are you asking if combobox has a name? :\

Comment: No. what kind of data does the dropdown hold ?

Comment: @rags Sorry for the confusion. My question was directed to pKo.

Comment: @pKo - can you explain a little more about how this control works? I'm not sure if you're describing an ordinary combobox, or possibly something with auto-completion.

Comment: I've always heard them named as simply a combo box. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 4):

### **Type-ahead Filter**:

If the field when entered displays a drop-down of all eligible values, and when the user starts typing into the field the options in the drop-down is reduced by  hiding non-matching values, then this is a *type-ahead filter*.

[image]

### **Auto-Suggest Field**:

A type-ahead field which does not display the drop-down when first entered, instead waiting for the user to type some characters before then providing a drop-down of suggestions is known as an *auto-suggest field*.

[image]

Some auto-suggest implementations will do a fuzzy match (see how my typing of "my ach" resulted in "my school" as a suggestion). This typically doesn't occur with type-ahead filters (usually because type-ahead filters are used for fields with a controlled vocabulary, not free-form text, and thus the range of options are defined and limited).

### **Combo-box**:

If the field when entered displays a drop-down of all eligible values, and when the user starts typing into the field the first matching value in the drop-down is selected (without hiding non-matching values), then this is a *combo box*.

[image]

Note that since non-matching values are not hidden the operator can use the arrow keys to move the selected option up or down. I have found this handy in that I might want to select the last of the options that start with the letter "S" and so I type an "T" and then use the up-arrow cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to a combo-box

[image]